# Load more list with JSON array Android

Tags: android, json, listview

I have to know about the JSON array parse and load in ListView with functioning like load more data on scrolling event.

Below is my class code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String URL = "API-URL";
int page_number = 1;
ListView lv;
ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    new PerformTask().execute();
}
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private class PerformTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String json="";
        try {

            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            json = jsonParser.getJSONdata(URL,page_number++);
            Log.e("jsonResponse", json + "");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (!result.equals("")) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray dataArray = jsonObj.optJSONArray("key");
                for(int i = 0; i<dataArray.length(); i++){
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> dataArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                    JSONArray dataArray_inner = dataArray.getJSONArray(i);
                    for(int j = 0; j<dataArray_inner.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject object22 = dataArray_inner.optJSONObject(j);
                        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("your_key", object22.getString("key_data"));
                        hashMap.put("your_key", object22.getString("post_content"));
                        dataArrayList.add(hashMap);
                    }
                    data.add(dataArrayList);
                }
                if(data.size() > 0){
                    Log.e("Data ","Data are available");

                    AdapterMain adapter = new AdapterMain(MainActivity.this, data);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                    lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
                            int threshold = 1;
                            int count = lv.getAdapter().getCount();
                            if (i == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                                if (lv.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                                        - threshold) {
                                    // Execute LoadMorePerformTask AsyncTask;
                                    new LoadMorePerformTask().execute();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                        }
                    });
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private class LoadMorePerformTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading more...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String json="";
        try {

            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            json = jsonParser.getJSONdata(URL,page_number++);
            Log.e("jsonResponse", json + "");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (!result.equals("")) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray dataArray = jsonObj.optJSONArray("key");
                for(int i = 0; i<dataArray.length(); i++){
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> dataArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                    JSONArray dataArray_inner = dataArray.getJSONArray(i);
                    for(int j = 0; j<dataArray_inner.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject object22 = dataArray_inner.optJSONObject(j);
                        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("your_key", object22.getString("key_data"));
                        hashMap.put("your_key", object22.getString("key_data"));
                        dataArrayList.add(hashMap);
                    }
                    data.add(dataArrayList);
                }
                if(data.size() > 0){
                    Log.e("Data ","Data are available");
                    int lv_position = lv.getLastVisiblePosition();
                    AdapterMain adapter = new AdapterMain(MainActivity.this, data);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                    lv.setSelectionFromTop(lv_position, 0);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

Adapter class code available here.

```
public class AdapterMain extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> arraylist;
protected int count;

public AdapterMain(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> numberlist) {
    mContext = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(numberlist);
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView title1, description1, title2, description2;
    RelativeLayout rel_second;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arraylist.size();
}

@Override
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getItem(int position) {
    return arraylist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view, null);
        holder.rel_second = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rel_second);
        holder.title1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title1);
        holder.description1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description1);
        holder.title2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title2);
        holder.description2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description2);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    // Set the results into TextView
    holder.title1.setText(arraylist.get(position).get(0).get("key1"));
    holder.description1.setText(arraylist.get(position).get(0).get("key2"));

        holder.rel_second.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.title2.setText(arraylist.get(position).get(1).get("key1"));
        holder.description2.setText(arraylist.get(position).get(1).get("key2"));

    // Listen for ListView Item Click
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
          // Click Perform of Item
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

JSONParser class is here.

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
public JSONParser() {
}

public String getJSONdata(String URL, int pageNumber){
    String response_str = "";
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
        post.addHeader(new BasicHeader("parameter_key", ""+pageNumber));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        response_str=sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response_str;
}

}
```

And this is Gradle file code.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "testdemoapp.sandy.com.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'

}
```

In this I get problem with load more data on scroll. sometimes it called AsyncTask twice and load more data than required.

If anyone have any idea than please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes because async take time to update your data while it still get scrolling and it again perform your operation ,put log to understand exact problem

Comment: I put progressDialog on AsyncTask execution so, when it is executed user will wait for getting data and finish progress task. but, problem I getting some times is AsyncTask call and I'm waiting to finish process than after finish that process start new one automatically.

Comment: when recyclerview get last item your asynctask will call but it create new thread so your main thread get scrolling event so again it call asynctask and asynctask will be execute one by one

Comment: you have to manage this behavior using condition

Comment: I manage it using condition with position of scrolling item and total available items in listview.

Comment: And yes, this was not happens every time. it was happens sometimes only.

Comment: put log with totalitem above `new LoadMorePerformTask().execute();` you will get idea

Comment: try to use recycler view instead of list view for growing lists and async task loader instead of async task for network requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use boolean for that.

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
                            int threshold = 1;
                            int count = lv.getAdapter().getCount();
                            if (i == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                                if (lv.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                                        - threshold) {
                                    // Execute LoadMorePerformTask AsyncTask;
                                    new LoadMorePerformTask().execute();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                        }
                    });
```

The problem is here in your code. You are create request every list reaches to its bottom. You need to keep a boolean `isLoaded = false` and before firing the request when list reaches to its bottom check if `isLoaded` is `true` then fire the request and in your async task you can set the boolean true when result is received and set it to false after firing the request.

```
if (i == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
         if (lv.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count- threshold) {
            // Execute LoadMorePerformTask AsyncTask;                                  
              if(isLoaded){
               new LoadMorePerformTask().execute();
              isLoaded=false
       }
       }
```

and in aysc

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
         isLoaded = true; //and your rest of the code}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: -->Mr.Sandy exact what i was convey to you and @Zeeshan nice answer

Comment: I have added my answer for more understanding. @PriteshVadhiya You can upvote on nice answer :P

Comment: Just be sure to make isLoaded = true; only if the executed request has valid data to it's response, otherwise you will get the same error.